# Executar aplicação PHP (Zend Framework) no servidor

Tags: php, zend

já deixo claro que não sou programador PHP e sim Java, mas tenho que subir uma aplicação da minha empresa em uma instância na AWS (Amazon Web Services).

Bem, estou com dificuldade, até porque é a primeira vez que trabalho com projetos 
PHP. Tenho uma maquina rodando Apache2 MySQL e o PHP5.5 (espero que satisfaça o deploy). Pelo que me parece a aplicação foi desenvolvida cm o Zend Framework.

Realizei a copia da aplicação para o caminho relativo no servidor `/var/www/html`

Agora não sei qual o próximo passo. Como realizo o "start" na aplicação.

Para ajudar aqui está o projeto no qual o apache esta servindo

[http://trust.joocebox.com](http://trustbox.joocebox.com/)

### EDIÇÃO

Bem pessoal depois de uma longa conversa com o Édipo (que foi de grande valia), infelizmente não conseguimos rodar a aplicação.

Mas não desisti! Criai uma nova instancia instalando o LAMP server assim como fiz o Download do Zend e copiei o conteudo da pasta `library` (do framework) para dentro da `library` do meu projeto, mas o mesmo apresenta erro 404! Alguém sabe o que posso estar tentando fazer para sanar o problema?

Abaixo segue o log:

```
[Wed Apr 15 17:39:59.956167 2015] [:error] [pid 7336] [client
177.157.34.20:13725] script '/opt/lampp/htdocs/trustbox/index.php' not found or unable to stat cat: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-172-30-0-15.pid: Permission denied cat: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-172-30-0-15.pid: Permission denied
```

Comment: Sabe se é Zend 1 ou Zend 2?

Comment: Oi Édipo. Infelizmente não sei te informar nesse exato momento. Mas provavelmente o 2

Comment: Essa aplicação é Zend 1

Comment: você fez aquele esquema de colocar a public como a "html" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depois de uma longa conversa, conseguimos subir a aplicação com esses passos.

1. Instalar o PHP 5.5, pois o servidor estava utilizando PHP 5.3 e o projeto usava sintaxes do PHP 5.4
2. Instalar o driver do mysql para o PDO
3. Habilitar o mod_rewrite
4. Copiar a aplicação para o servidor
5. Copiar o Zend Framework 1 para a pasta `library` do projeto.
6. Configurar o diretório public do projeto como a raiz do apache ao invés do `/var/www/html`.
7. Importar a base de dados
8. Configurar o banco de dados no arquivo `application/configs/application.ini`

Não foi fácil, a cada passo surgia um erro diferente, na verdade os passos nem foram feitos nessa ordem, coloquei uma ordem ideal aqui no stack.

Caso sua aplicação gere arquivos, como passo 9 sugiro:

9. Configurar permissão de escrita nas pastas em que arquivos são gerados.

Isso é muito comum para aplicações que tem upload de arquivos, por exemplo as imagens de um CMS.

O que nos ajudou a conseguir chegar nisso foi olhar os arquivos de log, um pouco da minha experiência para identificar possíveis causas de erros, habilitar os display erros nas configurações do `application.ini`.

**Erros e Soluções**

- Desconfiei da necessidade do item 1 pois tivemos um log indicando erro numa sintaxe que começava com `[`, olhando o arquivo vi a sintaxe de short array, vimos também a aplicação usando short tags para imprimir `<?=`, e elas são habilitadas no PHP 5.4 por padrão.
- Desconfiei da necessidade do item 2 pois estavamos recebendo `null` em um `foreach`, para confirmar, executamos um script para testar a conexão com o banco de dados.
- Desconfiei da necessidade do item 3 pois ao digitar qualquer rota da aplicação na url, recebia uma mensagem de arquivo não encontrado. O comportamento correto era direcionar para o `index.php`.
- Desconfiei da necessidade do item 5 pois estávamos tendo uma tela em branco e nos logs não estava encontrando a classe `Zend\Application`.
- Desconfiei da necessidade do item 6 pois estávamos tendo erros de rota, alem de ser necessário em produção.

**Referencias:**

- http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF1
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.quick-start.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375061/installing-pdo-driver-on-mysql-linux-server
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files
- http://jaydson.org/habilitar-mod_rewrite-no-apache/
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54280/discussion-on-answer-by-edipo-costa-reboucas-executar-aplicacao-php-zend-framew)